# No image view in android studio componet tree

Tags: android

I can't move the images, there isn't an image view on component tree field

it's liked this

[image]

here's also the xml file elements

[image]

I can't figure it out how to resolve this

hope you could help me

Comment: have you tried to close the XML and re open it, sometimes the render process goes wild, also try to rebuild the application

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll way down to see `ImageView`. You can also click `Images` to see the `ImageView` option. Also, change `match_parent` to `wrap_parent` on your `View` to see if you can move it then.